# How to identify user from server for processing requests

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

I would like to know how to identify user from server when any request from app is done. Like if I have logged into the app and want to update my profile and send the request to server. How will the server identify the request is from particular user ? I am using PHP as server language and storing user session using Shared Preferences.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: you should have a unique id which your server and app both understand, so in that case I believed it is the user id, which you can use when querying in your database, include this user id when making the server request and thats it

Comment: I thought of this option. The user id should be unique and encrypted if required. But I wanted to know if there are any other option  ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: How should the user ID be stored ? using Shared preferences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this outcome is to attach a unique identifier to the user(randomly generated) .Store this information along with the time,name and identifier of the user in the database. Also persist in the app, shared preference is alright. But consider using databases.A great one is realm for android. Then when any request is sent to the server send the name of user along with their identifier perform a query search with this information. Thus returning any info stored for this user.

Make any sense? Well there are other sophisticated approaches that can be tailored to your needs. the concept of shared preferences is to store small transient information. using a database permits much safer control over your data and managed operations asynchronously,which will pay a big role later when traffic is encountered. Consider web tokens as well for communication. JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard (RFC 7519) that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object. This information can be verified and trusted because it is digitally signed. JWTs can be signed using a secret (with the HMAC algorithm) or a public/private key pair using RSA.

Comment: I thought of this approach. But wanted to know if shared preferences is safe for this case ?

Comment: check updated answer. but if your operations are simple, then yes shared preferences is the way to go, because if you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd like to save use it.

Comment: I can save the user id as shared preferences and send the data along with user id to server using POST request right ?

Comment: well yes , what http library you using volley?

Comment: ya..its volley.

Comment: i beg you please switch to retrofit2, that will be the day your really happy. Volley made life hell.

Comment: sure, start here https://futurestud.io/tutorials/tag/retrofit , super good resource available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137234/discussion-between-caspain-and-nikhil).

Answer (score 1):

After successfully logged in to the app, save the `userId` locally (either in SQLite or SharedPreferences etc..). 
 Now everytime the user request from server, add that `userId` into the parameter list. 
 On the server side, first of all, check the userId, if it's `null` or not exist in the database, echo a `String` error message, otherwise proceed.